# Android - Is getResource() expensive?

Tags: android, resources

if i need to use a resource twice, is it better to store it in a String?

```
public class Testing extends Activity{
    private String c_stringName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
            c_stringName= this.getString(R.string.name);


}
}
```

Comment: Personally, if there are only very few use cases, I always avoid introducing unnecessary global variables and go on with local creation.

Comment: pretty certain that doing it either way won't cost you much of anything. don't worry about this type of stuff when building an app.  if you find there's a problem in terms of what's an expensive call, then look into changing how you access `name`. forget about it.  the problem i have with your code above is code clarity.  i would think about changing your use of fields and naming conventions to avoid confusing code

Comment: OK, thanks, i hv another question. I want to use some global constants/flags, is it better to create a static globalconstants class? or store them in the resource?

Comment: In most cases (IMHO) it might be best to use final static variables.

Comment: I think static final constants are a better way to go . Also for the original question you can do a profile using [TraceView](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dig down to the machine. The only difference between them is 1 reference.
it may seem like running multiple

```
c_stringName= this.getString(R.string.name);
```

is doing alot of work but its is the same and storing it into a string reference.